# Struggling with reading a text file and use of nested loops

Tags: python, nested-loops

I have attempted making a program that counts the number of occurrences of `"[AB]"` in a text file by searching each file individually (after loading and opening the file of course) but it doesn't seem to work, and I have no idea why.

Here is the program:

```
# NOTE: to make it work try making more functions that return values and check if
# for the beginning and end of the names
# to deal with the issue of local variable scope
#imports and reads first line of text file
print("Opening and closing file")
print("\nReading characters from file.")
text_file = open("chat3.txt", "r")

#prints current line just for checking(can remove later)
x = 0
ABcount = 0
d = 0
length = len(text_file.readlines())
print("There are no of lines ", length)
line = text_file.readline()
print("the current line is ", line)
#loop to find most commonly used words( a tuple with word(string): no of occurences(int))
print("point 1(before loop 1)")
for d in range(0, length):
    print("point 2(just into loop 1)")
    c = text_file.readline()#reads one line and stores it in variable c as a string
    count = len(c)#gets the length of line/no of characters in it as the next loop will iterate for each one
    print(c)
    print("point 3(in loop 1 after printing current line)")
    for x in range(0, count):
        print("This is count number", x+1)
        c2 = c[x]
        print("Current char is ", c2)
        if(('[' in c) and (c2 == '[')):
            start = c.index('[') + 1
            end = c.index(':')
            ABcount += 1
            print("There is/are ", ABcount, c[start:end])
        elif ( not '[' in c):
            break
text_file.close()
```

And `chat3.txt` content's are:

```
nn an an [AB:2020]
    [AB]
    [AB]
```

And the results from comp + running are

```
PS C:\Users\test> python counter.py
Opening and closing file

Reading characters from file.
There are no of lines  3
the current line is
point 1(before loop 1)
point 2(just into loop 1)

point 3(in loop 1 after printing current line)
point 2(just into loop 1)

point 3(in loop 1 after printing current line)
point 2(just into loop 1)

point 3(in loop 1 after printing current line)
PS C:\Users\test>
```

Comment: show a sample of the file text

Answer (score 1):

Use regex for this kind of thing

- t.txt

  ```
  Deserunt velit ipsum quis id aliquip commodo deserunt nulla officia ea dolor    reprehenderit pariatur. Sit laboris culpa in non et. Do laborum aliqua sunt voluptate occaecat anim magna eu. Est tempor ad non consectetur ea reprehenderit est quis et. Culpa eu sit amet est ullamco eiusmod et sit excepteur et cupidatat ullamco consectetur Lorem. Dolore elit dolore proident consectetur ipsum non. Sunt veniam incididunt duis veniam dolor sunt fugiat irure eiusmod.
  Nulla eiusmod voluptate aute tempor amet aliquip ad culpa dolor labore consequat ut ea proident. Qui minim velit elit ut excepteur fugiat nisi esse do et sit. Consequat est pariatur officia incididunt et pariatur laborum aute veniam do adipisicing.
  Eu aliqua ex ex irure. Mollit adipisicing est id quis eiusmod aliqua ullamco cupidatat. Lorem ea esse magna aliqua aute occaecat. Velit in enim ut ad eu magna amet fugiat labore amet ea.
  Adipisicing duis enim tempor ipsum magna duis. Consectetur ullamco adipisicing est aute fugiat qui excepteur nostrud nisi laboris ipsum. Officia sunt eiusmod consectetur dolor do et adipisicing duis cillum. Adipisicing esse exercitation deserunt labore Lorem deserunt consectetur ad laboris anim sit veniam ex ea. Minim voluptate pariatur dolor adipisicing commodo voluptate consectetur aute id officia irure elit. Cillum eiusmod esse nulla enim nostrud mollit voluptate incididunt ullamco anim cillum officia.
  ```
- script

  ```
  with open('r.txt','r') as file:
       f=file.read()
  import re
  re.findall('ab',f)
  print(re.findall('ab',f))
  # ['ab', 'ab', 'ab', 'ab', 'ab', 'ab', 'ab', 'ab']
  ```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, it does not enter your loop because when you first call `readlines`, it set the cursor at the end of the file and so the next `readline` returns nothing. This might help: [Why the second time I run "readlines" on the same file nothing is returned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524528/why-the-second-time-i-run-readlines-on-the-same-file-nothing-is-returned)

If you want to loop a file line by line just do `for line in file:`

For the rest, as suggested in other answers there are most certainly better way to do this, but I believe it is not the question here.