# Why doesn't `for line in f` print anything after `.readlines()`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

```
with open("data.txt", "r+") as f:
    if f.readlines() == []:
        f.write(input("Enter your name : "))
        f.write("\n" + input("Enter your name_roll no (javets_6890) : "))
        f.write("\n" + input("Enter the password for your mail id : "))
        f.write("\n" + input("Enter your roll number : "))
        f.write("\n" + input("Enter your admission number : "))
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

I am trying to print the lines of the "data.txt" file containing some text, but when I execute this code, nothing gets printed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because [`.readlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=readlines#io.IOBase.readlines) consumes the file buffer, so by the time you iterate `for line in f`, the file pointer is already at the end of the file. You can check with [`.tell()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=readlines#io.IOBase.tell) to see that the file pointer is not anymore at the start of the file.

```
with open("data.txt", "r+") as f:
    print(f.tell())  # Prints 0
    if f.readlines() == []:
        # ... your code ...
    print(f.tell())  # Prints total bytes written in file
```

In fact, the docs mentions that they both do the same thing:

> Note that it’s already possible to iterate on file objects using `for line in file: ...` without calling `file.readlines()`.

The typical solution is to use [`.seek(0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=readlines#io.IOBase.seek) to rewind the file pointer back to the start of the file (as shown in [Why the second time I run “readlines” on the same file nothing is returned?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3524543/2745495))

But from your use case, I suggest *not* using `readlines()` to check if the file is empty. Instead, use a combination of [`.tell()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=readlines#io.IOBase.tell) and [`.seek()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=readlines#io.IOBase.seek) to check if the file is empty.

```
from io import SEEK_END

with open("data.txt", "r+") as f:
    # Move the file pointer to the end of the file
    f.seek(0, SEEK_END)
    if f.tell() == 0:
        # The file pointer is still at the start of the file
        # This means the file is empty
        f.write(input("Enter your name : "))
        f.write("\n" + input("Enter your name_roll no (javets_6890) : "))
        f.write("\n" + input("Enter the password for your mail id : "))
        f.write("\n" + input("Enter your roll number : "))
        f.write("\n" + input("Enter your admission number : "))
    # Rewind file pointer back to the start of the file
    f.seek(0)
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

I think this is better since you don't have to read the contents of the file twice.